# Which is the correct form and under what topic does this fall?

Tags: infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund

1) I stand before the court requesting that ...

2) I stand before the court to request that ...

Is only #2 correct? Are both correct? And why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both perfectly grammatical. They have a slightly different meaning.

The first one uses a participial clause, which tells the hearer something more about either the subject ("I") or the whole predication ("I stand before the court"). (It is possible to analyse this either way, but it doesn't make any difference).

The second one uses a "to" infinitive clause. Sometimes this is required by the particular verb or adjective that governs it (eg "I **want** to request that ..." or  "I am **eager** to request that ..." But in this case it is not required by some other word, so it will be interpreted as a purpose clause: "**in order** to request that ...".

So, they have similar meanings in this case, but the first one is just saying that you are standing there and requesting, but the second says that you are standing there for the purpose of making the requests.